# Material Design Action Bar compatible from GingerBread onwards (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, material-design, android-compatibility

I want a clean action bar which support from api 10 - api 21 to implement in my app. I have gone through different tutorials, developer documents from google and some examples provided at the developer site. Do we have simple solution for a clean code and easy to follow method for enabling `Actionbar` in an android app, (preferably which can works well with material design and features in lollipop without affecting anything bad in earlier versions). Also I need to create a navigation tab in `Actionbar`, the sample code provided on the developer site is not working for me.

Any suggestions, writes ups, tutorial links are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "But even the developer site provided codes contain DEPRECATED methods" -- so? They deprecated various navigation options (e.g., tabs) in Android 5.0. If you do not want to use deprecated methods, do not use the deprecated methods. What specifically is your problem with using either the native action bar or the `appcompat-v7` backport of the action bar? You may also wish to stop shouting.

Comment: Sorry my intention was to just highlight it not to shout. :( my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most useful official introductory posts is this one:

[**AppCompat v21 - Material Design for Pre-Lollipop Devices!**](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

This shows you how to backport the new `Toolbar` all the way back to Gingerbread, as they have done with the Play Store app.

See also the [**Material Design on Android Checklist**](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/material-design-on-android-checklist.html) post which is also great.

And don't miss the [**How to upgrade your app’s design from Holo to Material Design**](https://medium.com/@orhnsnmz/how-to-upgrade-your-apps-design-from-holo-to-material-design-a-case-study-f77e33a528c8) article!

Love Material Design ....

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Toolbar from the Android Support Libary v7.

[Toolbar in Gingerbread](http://hmkcode.com/add-actionbar-to-android-2-3-x/)